# Why web api returns unathorized error code?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, authorization, azure-ad-b2c, maui

So i got .NET Maui as a frontend app and .NET Web Api as a backend. Api is already published to Azure. B2C inside my Maui app working fine so i think i set up it correctly. But i got unathorized error when i try to acess my secured web api.I register my api inside Azure B2C and grant offline_access and openid. Also added scope for api and grant access to my Maui app.

My api program class looks like this(here microsoft identity configuration and controller with authorization):

```
//Other code
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.RequireAuthorization();
```

And also appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",  
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://myorg.b2clogin.com",
    "Domain": "myorg.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "WEB_API_CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi"
  }
}
```

Here is mine auth service from Maui app:

```
public class BaseAuthService : IAuthService
    {
        private readonly IPublicClientApplication authClient;        

        protected BaseAuthService(IPublicClientApplication authClient)
        {
            this.authClient = authClient;
        }

        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenSilent(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var accounts = await authClient.GetAccountsAsync(Constants.SignInPolicy);
                var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

                if (firstAccount == null)
                    return null;                

                return await authClient.AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                       .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task LogoutAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var accounts = await authClient.GetAccountsAsync();

            foreach (var account in accounts)
                await authClient.RemoveAsync(account);
        }

        public Task<AuthenticationResult> SignInInteractively(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return authClient.AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)                
                             .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

And also maui dependency and constants class:

```
 public static class DependencyExtension
    {
        public static void RegisterAuthService(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var clientApplicationBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Constants.ClientId)
#if ANDROID
            .WithParentActivityOrWindow(() => Platform.CurrentActivity)
#endif
#if WINDOWS
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost");
#else
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth");
#endif

            services.AddSingleton(new AuthService(clientApplicationBuilder.Build()));

            var b2cClientApplicationBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Constants.ClientId)
#if ANDROID
                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(() => Platform.CurrentActivity)
#endif
#if WINDOWS
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost");
#else
                .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth");
#endif

            services.AddSingleton(new AuthServiceB2C(
                b2cClientApplicationBuilder
                    .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(Constants.IosKeychainSecurityGroups)
                    .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignIn)                    
                    .Build()));
        }
    }
```

```
public static class Constants
    {
        public static readonly string ClientId = "MAUI_APP_CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE"; 
        public static readonly string ApiScope = "https://myorg.onmicrosoft.com/WEB_API_CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE/access_as_user";
        public static readonly string[] Scopes = { ApiScope };        
        public static readonly string TenantName = "MyOrg";
        public static readonly string TenantId = $"{TenantName}.onmicrosoft.com";
        public static readonly string SignInPolicy = "B2C_1_susi";
        public static readonly string AuthorityBase = $"https://{TenantName}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{TenantId}/";
        public static readonly string AuthoritySignIn = $"{AuthorityBase}{SignInPolicy}";
        public static readonly string IosKeychainSecurityGroups = "com.microsoft.adalcache";
    }
```

So when i try access my api i get unothorized error, please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to call api from this method:

```
public async Task GetWeatherForecast()
    {      

        try
        {     
            var client = new HttpClient();            
            
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast");
            
            message.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {acessToken}");
        
            var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
            
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            await DisplayAlert("Api responce", responseString, "ok");           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Api responce", "error", "ok");
        }       
    }
```